# When are numbers nouns?

Tags: grammar, numbers, word-classes

In my native language, Portuguese, numbers have officially been in various classes, from adjectives and nouns to "quantifiers" and determiners.

I'm thinking that perhaps we can't group them all, simply because they behave differently. For example, "ten" works differently from "million". Multiplying by 2, you get "twenty" and "**two** million**s**". A million is a noun, like a potato or a third; while "ten" is different. "Twelve" and "a dozen" are the same in meaning, but grammatically behave in different ways.

Why? In other languages, this happens with other words. Some may agree in gender/number with the object they quantify, like nouns do. Can we grammatically divide numbers in different classes? How would this work? Would another class be required? How would this system vary from language to language (I'd appreciate if you'd make a comparison between English and some other language of your choice)?

Comment: As a monolingual English speaker, and writing off the cuff, I would say that English numeral terms are nouns when they stand for specific abstract quantities or for numerals.   In "One and one make two," all the numeral terms are nouns that stand for abstract quantities.   In "Write a three in the third box," the numeral term "three" stands for a numeral, i.e. a symbol that usually stands for a specific abstract quantity.

Comment: I'm going to try to summarise the different questions i think you're asking here, just to make sure i'm following:
(1) Why don't number words behave in a syntactically uniform manner?
(2) If number words *do* cross-cut syntactic categories, which categories to they belong to (this raises interesting questions about the syntax/semantics interface, e.g. if number words are semantically uniform, why don't they behave the same syntactically?)
(3) Do we need a distinct syntactic category 'numeral'?
(4) To what extent to numeral systems differ cross-linguistically?

Comment: @James, in "Write a three in the third box.", wouldn't the "three" be a noun, as it is substitutable be "word"?

Comment: @PElliot, precisely my questions; only yours are written better. :) Should I edit the post and replace the last paragraph with those?

Comment: If you like, but it's probably just me. I just wanted to check that i understood. Greville Corbett (1978: http://www.academia.edu/746864/Universals_in_the_syntax_of_cardinal_numerals) argues all numerals are somewhere between nouns and adjectives - he tentatively claims that, universally, the numerals which are more noun-like are numerically higher than the numerals which are more adjective-like. For example, the numerals in English which take an article are numerically higher than those which don't. It's an interesting claim and it's totally mysterious to me why it would hold.

Comment: @PElliott, that's curious, in Portuguese and French it happens too! And in Esperanto, every number below one million is not quite a noun nor an adjective, although each one has an associated noun, and each noun an associated adjective.

Comment: @JMCF125:   Yes, "three" is a noun in "Write a three in the third box."   So the latter is another example of a numeral term being a noun.

Comment: @JamesGrossman This is down to the use/mention distinction, right? We can use number terms to *mention* numeral symbols, but really it should have invisible scare quotes around it. Whenever a very low (numerically) number like 'three' comes with an article, it seems to me we're mentioning rather than using it, e.g.
(a) A 'three' is a single digit number.
(b) #A 'three' is an odd number.
(b) sounds odd because the article biases the *mention* interpretation. It sounds fine if we drop the article:
(c) Three is a round number.

Comment: @JamesGrossman BTW, wasn't trying to refute what you've said, just fleshing it out a bit.

Comment: I know.  But I'm a little unclear about the use/mention distinction.   As far as I can tell, the distinction that your examples highlight is the distinction between numeral words that stand for symbols and numeral words that stand for specific abstract qualities.  In a) "three" clearly stands for a symbol.  Witness the fact that "three" is a two digit number (10) in base three.   In b) we are clearly talking about a specific abstract quantity, namely one member of the set of odd numbers.  Since said abstract quantity is unique, you can't use "a/an" in the NP that refers to it.

Answer (score 2):

Each word is classified by what is permissible in the instances in which it appears. In English, "three" can be a noun, an adjective, a pronoun, or a numeral. I will use French as the second language in my examples. If a word can be replaced by another word without changing the grammar of the sentence, the two words have the same grammatical class *in that instance*.

#### Noun

- I have a **three**.
- I have a **(playing) card (with the value three)**.
- J'ai un **trois**.
- J'ai une **carte (à jouer) (avec la valeur trois)**.

#### Adjective (English)

- I have **three** cats.
- I have **small** cats.

#### Determiner (French)

- J'ai **trois** chats. (I have **three** cats.)
- J'ai **des** chats. (I have **some** cats.)

#### Adjective (French)

- J'ai les **trois** chats. (I have the **three** cats.)
- J'ai les **petits** chats. (I have the **small** cats.)

#### Pronoun

- **Three** are eating.
- **They** are eating.
- **Trois** mangent.
- **Ils** mangent.

#### Numeral

- One, two, **three**.
- One, two, **four**.
- Un, deux, **trois**.
- Un, deux, **quatre**.

Note: "numeral" can be hard to differentiate from the other classes. It doesn't work if you replace "three" with a word from a different class:

- One, two, **three**
- One, two, ***card**
- One, two, ***some**
- One, two, ***small**
- One, two, ***they**

So, "three" isn't a noun, an adjective, a pronoun, **and** a numeral at the same time, it is only one of those at a time. You should now be able to apply the same process in Portuguese to work out when numbers are nouns.

In regards to your question about the *declination* of numbers (i.e. whether they are invariable, can be singular or plural, etc.), note that some nouns are invariable (in certain contexts), and some have to be declined.

- I am drinking milk.

Not:

- I am drinking *a milk. (allowable if "a milk" is the ellipsis of "a **serving** of milk")
- I am drinking *milks.

It seems from your question that in Portuguese, "ten" is invariable, while "million" can be singular or plural. This doesn't change the grammatical class.